# How to render anchor element inside <td> element using jquery in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using ajax and dynamically manipulating `<td>` elements inside success returning of data using java script.

I have tried and everything is running fine , I am getting data inside my `<td>` elements but unfortunately can not handle how to put anchor tag inside some `<td>` elements as those returning data containing some files that is present on server folder so I need to make anchor tag so that user can open the file .

```
    $("#Status").on('change', function () {
        $("#Table11").find("tr:not(:first)").remove();
        debugger;
        var Status = $("#Status").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/BusinessCaseProcess/GetRec',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { Status: Status },
            success: function (response) {
                debugger;
                var trHTML = '';
                $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                    trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.Title + '</td><td>' + item.EmployeeName + '</td><td>' + item.Department + '</td><td>' + item.SubDepartment + '</td><td>' + item.Station + '</td><td>' + item.DateOfRequest + '</td><td>' + item.TrackingID + '</td><td><a href="' + item.file + '">Primary </a></td><td><a href="~/BusinessCaseProcessUploadedFiles/' + item.otherFile + '">Secondary </a></td><td>' + item.HeadOfDepartmentStatus + '</td><td>' + item.HRMStatus + '</td><td>' + item.HeadOfITStatus + '</td><td>' + item.FinanceControllerStatus + '</td><td>' + item.VPPStatus + '</td></tr>';
                });
                $('#Table11').append(trHTML);
            }
        })
```

As you can see i am trying to make anchor tag inside td elements in code. The variable is containing the file name , and inside href i am giving folder name , i need to open the file on click just like anchor tag does.

Comment: you want to `download` the file from `anchor` tag or open the file in `browser`?

Comment: I just need to open the file

Comment: try setting `_target='blank'` in the anchor tag, but usually not all files opens in browser, like `PDF` will open but may be other type of files might get downloaded.